# Uncaught ReferenceError, Splide is not defined at HTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, css

I have written code for thumbnail slider following an example in the following link [splidejs.com/getting-started](https://splidejs.com/getting-started) for primary slider.
Tried to look again and again but I don't see anything in the output even pictures are not shown. Header files already linked through CDN(CSS and js)

Below is the code:

HEADER FILES

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/css/splide.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog.css">
```

JS HEADER FILE

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**HTML CODE**

```html
<div class="splide">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="pic2.jpg"></li>
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="pic1.jfif"></li>
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="">pic.png</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  new Splide("#secondary-slider", {
    fixedWidth: 100,
    height: 60,
    gap: 10,
    rewind: true,
    cover: true,
    pagination: false,
  }).mount();
});
```

Comment: Why do you attach the same event twice to document?

Comment: I just copied from the above link, I made a mistake but after removing the error still remain

Comment: if it's undefined, I imagine there is an error in how you are importing the files. Add your headers to your post so people can check your imports

Comment: Already added but js link does not display above while included, I don't know why

Comment: Can you please add all of your headers which includes all js, because I can not see any slider JS file here

Comment: I see a Splide css file but no JavaScript file import

Comment: I have not added less than sign at the start, because if I do the link does not display

Comment: I have the same issue when I change the selector name

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your javascript code you are trying to mount Splide on "#secondary-slider" but I can't see this id in your HTML.
Try fixing this with either adding an a corresponding id property to your div with with class "splide" or call Splide mount on ".splide"

Comment: What you're assuming is not what the error in title refers to. `Splide` is not defined meaning that at the time `Splide` is called the interpreter had no clue about any `Splide` prototype function. Open the terminal and write into it `new Splide()` and hit Enter. What error do you get? Has nothing to do with any IDs.

Answer (score -1):

Call JS after the HTML code:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@1.3.3/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>`

```
  new Splide('.splide').mount();
</script>
```

Should work
https://github.com/Splidejs/splide/issues/9#issuecomment-573321831
This helped me.